# MySQL Count function - WHERE function respond an error

Tags: php, mysql, echo, where-clause

Connection to database is made...

trying to get result with:

```
<?php
 $res = mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM ' . 'jobs', WHERE country = 'USA', $con);
    if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM))
    {
       $usa = trim($row[0]);
    }
    else
    {
       $usa = 'Error';
    }
    ?>
```

Failure message: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /footer.php on line...

Help me get this WHERE function working: WHERE country = 'USA'

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The reason is you glued this query wrong. Do this instead of the 2nd line

`$res =  mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM jobs  WHERE country = "USA"', $con);`

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$res = mysql_query('SELECT Count(*) FROM jobs WHERE country = "USA" ', $con);
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array($res, MYSQL_NUM))
{
   $usa = trim($row[0]);
}
else
{
   $usa = 'Error';
}
?>
```